# How to set PPPOE in kali OS

Tags: linux, pppoe

How can we create PPPOE in kali OS.
I previously set it in BT4 via "sudo pppoeconf", but its not working here.
Secondly I tried GUI and gone to DSL and set all the values.But it again not worked for me.Have anyone done this on this OS

Comment: "But it again not worked for me". How exactly did it "not work"?  Did you get any responses/logs when trying to connect? Credential failure? Connection failure? Adapter failure?  What exactly happened when you tried "sudo pppoeconf"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set PPPOE in kali linux 2016.4](https://superuser.com/questions/1114485/how-to-set-pppoe-in-kali-linux-2016-4)

Answer (score 1):

**Network Manager > VPN Connections > Configure VPN > DSL > add > user: password: seve **strong text****

Answer (score 0):

Actually you'd better do this, in case there is no pppoeconf preinstalled

```
wget https://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/pppoe
tar -xzvf ...
cd .../src/
./configure
make 
make install
pppoe-setup
pppoe-start
```

In my case, I used mobile hotspot. But you can download it even from other OS, and then move from /dev/sdaX (ntfs-3g for Windows)

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal as root & type command:

> nm-connection-editor

Then click on " ADD " & select "DSL".
Fill your username,service,password & save it.

Then go to settings > network > wired connection > wired settings > general & tick on "connect automatically when available " .

BOOM !! You are connected to internet although you can't see wired connected notification.

Comment: The proper thing to do, instead of submitting the same answer to multiple questions, is to flag the question as a duplicate of the question you answered.