# How to set PPPOE in kali linux 2016.4

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, internet, kali-linux

How can I create PPPOE in kali OS.  set dsl pppoeconf net setting in kali linux command

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo pppoeconf` and answer the questions asked.

To turn on the dsl connection:

```
sudo pon dsl-provider
```

To turn off:

```
sudo poff dsl-provider
```

Answer (score 0):

To open Network Manager, open the Terminal and type:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

You will be greeted with the Network Manager. Now add your DSL connection with the username and password and connect.